# Manipulate the list. (Argument does not have the correct form for a variable specification.)

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

Why doesn't this work:

```
p = {1,2,3};
Manipulate[{p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}, {p[[1]], 0, 1}, {p[[2]], 0, 1}, {p[[3]], 0, 
      1}]
"Manipulate argument {p[[1]],0,1} does not have the correct form for \
a variable specification"
```

Neither this:

```
Manipulate[{Indexed[p, 1], Indexed[p, 2], 
  Indexed[p, 3]}, {Indexed[p, 1], 0, 1}, {Indexed[p, 2], 0, 
  1}, {Indexed[p, 3], 0, 1}]
```

and how do I use lists in Manipulate w/o stupid hacks like p[i] and then iterating over it with For?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour] (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Did you try this?  `ClearAll[p]; Manipulate[{p[1], p[2]}, {p[1], 0, 1}, {p[2], 0, 1}]`

Comment: @LouisB yes, and I have mentioned that in my question. I then have to collect all those p[1],p[2]... into a list for further processing, which is unhandy. Mathematica is all about lists as I see, so why there's no simple way to use them with Manipulate?

Comment: You may get better answers if you edit your question to describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to use nested `With` as shown below. Note that the hack `i=i` is mandatory, and you can't `tmp[[i]]=#` because you would get `` Set::setps: {FE` $1462$$530,FE`$1463$$530,FE`$1464$$530} in the part assignment is not a symbol. ``

```
ClearAll[p, list, tmp];
list = {1, 2, 3};
MakeTable[] := Table[p[i], {i, 1, Length@list}];
With[{vars = MakeTable[],
  controls = Sequence @@
    Table[{p[i],
      list[[i]],
      With[{i = i, tmp = MakeTable[]},
       (Slider[Dynamic[tmp[[i]],
           (tmp = 
              Normal@SparseArray[
                Join[{i -> #}, 
                 Table[j -> list[[j]], {j, 1, Length@list}]]]; 
             list = tmp) &], {0, 10}]) &]},
     {i, 1, Length@list}]},
 {Manipulate[vars, controls], Dynamic@list}]
```

[image: manipulate a list]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

You're getting an error because `p={1,2,3}` is a list of numbers. Essentially you have `Manipulate[1,{1,0,1}]`. `1` is not a variable so you can't range over it, i.e. `{1,0,1}` makes no sense. It needs to be in the form `Manipulate[expr,{u,umin,umax}]`. See [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

[image]

If you do `Manipulate[{x,y,z},{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1}]` it will work, but you just get three sliders that vary the output point, so I don't really see the purpose of that. Having `{x,y,z}` as the expression input `expr` is pretty boring.

[image]